# How to convert XML to Plain Text

Tags: xml, xslt

Do you know how to convert XML to Plain Text file(example.txt)? I already use just copy text from browser & paste to memo app method. But I want to make this more easy way.

1. XML Code

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="example.xsl"?>
<products>
    <begin>&#60;&#60;&#60;begin&#62;&#62;&#62;</begin>
    <mapid>&#60;&#60;&#60;mapid&#62;&#62;&#62;{Sku}</mapid>
    <price>&#60;&#60;&#60;price&#62;&#62;&#62;{Price}</price>
    <pname>&#60;&#60;&#60;pname&#62;&#62;&#62;{Title}</pname>
    <pgurl>&#60;&#60;&#60;pgurl&#62;&#62;&#62;{Permalink}</pgurl>
    <deliv>&#60;&#60;&#60;deliv&#62;&#62;&#62;0</deliv>
    <ftend>&#60;&#60;&#60;ftend&#62;&#62;&#62;</ftend>
</products>
```

2. example.xsl code

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="products">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

3. XML result on Chrome

```html
<<<begin>>>
<<<mapid>>>FOOD19278
<<<price>>>35
<<<pname>>>example product
<<<pgurl>>>https://example.com/
<<<deliv>>>0
<<<ftend>>>
```

4. Expect Plain text file example.txt

```html
<<<begin>>>
<<<mapid>>>FOOD19278
<<<price>>>35
<<<pname>>>example product
<<<pgurl>>>https://example.com/
<<<deliv>>>0
<<<ftend>>>
```

Comment: There is no difference between the Chrome output and the desired output (And - I checked it - between the Firefox output). So there is no question to answer, because the result is already achieved.

Comment: @zx485 Thank you for comment. You are right. Chrome or other browser output is same. But I want to make example.txt file not just print on browser.

Comment: It is not clear what you are looking for. If you want to run XSLT outside of or without a browser you can of course do that using a standalone XSLT processor or using an XML or XSLT IDE/editor. Depending on your platform/OS you might have built-in options or installable packages and you can of course install third party software as well. These days the current version of XSLT is XSLT 3 and it is implemented by Saxon 9.8 or 9.9 for the Java and the .NET platform, you can find it on Sourceforge https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/.

Comment: And its documentation for the command line use at http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/commandline/ e.g. `java -jar saxon9he.jar -xsl:example.xsl -s:source.xml -o:example.txt`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thank you for your comment. I don't want to run XSLT outside of browser. I want to convert 3. XML result on Chrome to Plain text file like example.txt not XML output like example.xml. As you know 3. XML result on Chrome has xml code that invisible on browser view. We can find xml code through chrome source code view. Anyway If you know the method please let me know.

Comment: What exactly does the source view of Chrome show for your example? And it what way do you want to use Chrome or another browser to create a text file? By saving the XSLT result rendered in the browser? You say you use "copy text from browser & paste" and you "want to make this more easy way", can you be more specific what you expect the browser to do?